# Regular expression to delete everything in a file except a string

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm trying to parse some svg coordinates with Notepad++. I would like take the coordinate set of each layer and put the coordinates inside [] to make it ready to be used in a javascript array.

The svg file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 14.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build     43363)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN"   "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="800px"
 height="900px" viewBox="0 0 800 900" enable-background="new 0 0 800 900"   xml:space="preserve">
<g id="Layer_3">
<polyline fill="none" stroke="#0000FF" stroke-width="3" points="33,108 66,141 99,174 99,207 132,207 165,207 165,240     "/>
</g>
<g id="Layer_4">
<polyline fill="none" stroke="#0000FF" stroke-width="3" points="132,306 165,306 165,339 165,372 132,405 99,405 99,438 132,438 
    165,438     "/>
</g>
<g id="Layer_5">
<polyline fill="none" stroke="#0000FF" stroke-width="3" points="198,339 231,339 264,372 297,372 330,405 363,438 396,438     "/>
</g>
<g id="Layer_6">
<polyline fill="none" stroke="#0000FF" stroke-width="3" points="198,174 198,273 231,306 264,306     "/>
</g>
<g id="Layer_7">
<polyline fill="none" stroke="#0000FF" stroke-width="3" points="231,174 231,240 264,273 297,273     "/>
</g>
<g id="Layer_9">
<polyline fill="none" stroke="#0000FF" stroke-width="3" points="396,306 462,306 495,339 495,372 528,405 528,438 561,438 
    594,471     "/>
</g>
<g id="Layer_10">
<polyline fill="none" stroke="#0000FF" stroke-width="3" points="660,504 561,504 495,504     "/>
</g>
</svg>
```

I would like the result to look something like this:

```
[33,108 66,141 99,174 99,207 132,207 165,207 165,240]

[132,306 165,306 165,339 165,372 132,405 99,405 99,438 132,438 165,438]

[198,339 231,339 264,372 297,372 330,405 363,438 396,438]

[198,174 198,273 231,306 264,306]

[231,174 231,240 264,273 297,273]

[396,306 462,306 495,339 495,372 528,405 528,438 561,438 594,471]

[660,504 561,504 495,504]
```

I'm quite new to regular expressions, but here's my feeble attempt:

search for: .+points="(.+")

replace with: [$1]

I'm stuck because the search part doesn't seem to search lines above the "points" string. How can I get rid of everything but the coordinates, even if there is garbage much higher in the document?

Comment: Don't parse XML with regular expressions. Use a real XML parser. This has been mentioned here on SO about a million times. Use the proper tool for the job, instead of trying to make everything a nail so you can use a hammer.

Comment: I'm not parsing dynamically. Can you explain why Notepadd++ shouldn't work for basic offline editing like this?

Comment: It will, but if it's a one-off thing you can use multiple operations to get the results you need and there's no need to try and do it in a single regex. If it's a recurring task (something you need to do regularly), use an XML parser that will simplify things for you drastically. (I'm confused, anyway; your question asks about retrieving the "points" values, but then asks why the part before "points" isn't being used. That seems clear: you asked for the "points" values. "Find the words that start with "c". Wait - it's not working right with the "a" and "b" words before the first "c" word."?)

Comment: I need to search for things until where the coordinates start in order to delete that stuff. The word "points" is the best way to identify where the wanted information begins.

To use your example I'm saying delete everything before c and also delete c. Keep what comes after c until there is d.

Anyway, I did some googling for "xml parsers" and that seemed to open up a whole new can of worms. I'm not sure if I have the time right now to start comparing and studying different options, so I'm happy that Notepad++ can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I have to agree in general with Ken White about not parsing XML with regexes. But if you want a quick and dirty solution in Notepad++ try this one (don't forget to check the option ". matches newline"):

Find:

```
.+?points="(.+?)\s*"
```

Replace:

```
[$1]\n\n
```

This will *almost* give you the anticipated result (you will still have to manually remove some trailing characters).

Comment: Thank you! Especially the ". matches newline" was valuable information! Your solution worked nicely!